# Is there any way to reset undo in ckeditor after setData?

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

I want reset the undo functionality after set Data method in ckeditor.

any one know please let me know.

```
editor.setData(content,function(){
    this.checkDirty();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the trouble of searching the clock
All roads do not work
I do not know the reason

[reset](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/api/CKEDITOR_plugins_undo_UndoManager.html#method-reset)

[resetDirty](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/api/CKEDITOR_editor.html#method-resetDirty)

[resetUndo](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/api/CKEDITOR_editor.html#method-resetUndo)

**The solution is**

```
CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.setData('Text_Html',function() { this.resetUndo(); });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [resetDirty()](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/api/CKEDITOR_editor.html#method-resetDirty)

> Resets the "dirty state" of the editor so subsequent calls to
>   checkDirty will return false if the user will not have made further
>   changes to the content.

```
alert( editor.checkDirty() ); // e.g. true

editor.resetDirty();

alert(editor.checkDirty() ); // false
```